Python + Polars: is there a way to identify some columns as "label" or "primary" columns (in opposition to "data" columns)?
join takes as argument on: the columns used to match two rows.
group_by takes as argument by: the columns used to match two rows to the same group.
Is there a nice way to mark certain columns as columns to be used for matching purposes, so that I can fetch them conveniently when computing on or by?
For example:
df = pl.DataFrame([ids_a, ids_b, data_x])
# pseudo code
df.mark_primary([ids_a.name, ids_b.name])

...

join_on = set(df.primaries()).intersection(other_df.primaries())
df.join(other_df, on=join_on)


There isn't a flag or marker.
However there are a couple alternatives that do kind-of do what you're looking for.
For joining you can do
pl.concat([df, other_df], how='align')
This gives you a full outer join over the columns that are the same between the two (or more) dfs.
For group_by you can use selectors
such as
import polars.selectors as cs
df.group_by(cs.starts_with('id')).agg(pl.col('a').sum())

This assumes that your "primary" columns are prefixed "id".

I can attach flags to columns in Polars: is there a way to use them in group_by or join? As for the concat suggestion: this does too much because not all the columns are worth aligning over.

How can you attach flags to columns?

I thought so based on: https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.flags.html and https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/series/api/polars.Series.flags.html
But I think it's not possible to set the flags because xs.flags["hello"] = False does nothing, but I am not yet sure. (The flags must all have boolean values)

Those flags are internal meta data, you can't alter or add to them.
